# Proof of the inverse square law for a uniformly bright sphere

Tags: radiation

On page 8 of  ["Radiative processes in Astrophysics"](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=LtdEjNABMlsC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=true) by Rybicki and Lightman they have a proof that the flux of a uniform sphere is inversely proportional to the distance of the sphere from the observer. I don't understand why they claim $\theta_c=\sin^{-1}R/r$, where the geometry is shown on pg 8, figure 1.6. It seems to me that its should rather be $\theta_c=\tan^{-1}R/r$. But then I don't think the proof would work. Any help in clarifying this for me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately Google's not allowing Page8 to be displayed. Do you have another source?

Comment: The same image is remade for [this homework set](http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~geoff/HEA/HEA_Problems.pdf) (NB pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look carefully at the figure, you will see that $r$ is the length of the *hypotenuse* (point $P$ to the center of the source), *not* the length of point $P$ to the tangent. Thus, we have that $\sin^{-1}R/r\equiv\theta_c$.

Comment: Thanks, I was mistaking the line going from P to the tangent of the sphere as the hypotenuse. But now I can appreciate, the hypotenuse is in fact the horizontal line in the figure. I see now this makes sense as it is ofcourse the tangent which is perpendicular to the radius.